# Value cannot be null in sportstore example

Tags: c#, null

I am having this problem when I want to implement IoC for sportstore example.

```
public WindsorControllerFactory()
{
    container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter(new ConfigResource("castle")));

    var controllerTypes = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                          where typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(t)
                          select t;

    foreach (Type t in controllerTypes)
    {
        container.AddComponentLifeStyle(t.FullName, t, LifestyleType.Transient);
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(Type controllerType)
    {
        return (IController)container.Resolve(controllerType);
    }
}
```

The error said that the value cannot be `null` in the `GetControllerInstance`.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting requests for things without types....

```
      protected override IController  GetControllerInstance(Type controllerType)
      {
          if (controllerType == null) { 
                return null; 
          }else{
                 return (IController)container.Resolve(controllerType);
           }
       }
```